# Surface Viewer of Matlab - Need explanation

Tags: matlab, fuzzy

How can this surface viewer be explained?  in other words, how can we describe/explain this graph in words?

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4KQO.jpg)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

The attached plot represents a 2-input, 2-output function where the two inputs are "distance" and "angle" while the two outputs are unknown quantities - one ranging between around -80 to +120 while the other output is described in terms of color by a colorbar that is not provided in the linked image.